# Convert and Split UTC time period to localtime

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

I know how to convert a date stored in UTC time in SQLite database, but I have a time duration stored. Like I have a `start_time`, `end_time` and `duration` in millis. Now, I can convert a date stored in utc to localtime with `datetime(start_time, 'localtime')` and same for the `end_time`.

But, when UTC is converted to local time, some duration will have different date in start_date and end_date.

For example, after converting date in localtime I have something like this:

```
start_time: 2016-10-21 23:50:00
end_time  : 2016-10-22 00:05:00
millis    : 900000
```

Now, I want to split this for a particular date while querying.
Like that should be split in query result in this 2 records:

1)

```
start_time: 2016-10-21 23:50:00
end_time  : 2016-10-21 23:59:59 or 2016-10-22 00:00:00
millis    : 600000
```

2)

```
start_time: 2016-10-22 00:00:00
end_time  : 2016-10-22 00:05:00
millis    : 300000
```

This should not be stored in database. Only while querying can I get the data like this? Because, I need to get the data for date based on localtime. So that I can also calculate the duration for a single day also.

Comment: With the [`start of day` modifier](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), write two queries for 1) and 2), then [combine](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) them.

Comment: @CL. How can I use start_of_day ? I saw but didn't understood how to query that for my needs..